# Swift Passing data from appDelegate to another class

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, appdelegate

I need to pass a variable from the AppDelegate to another class that I have created to hold global variables of the project and I'm not able to find a way to make it work.

This is the code in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
    println("Device's token is: \(deviceToken)")

    //Global Variables Class Instance
    let globals:Globals = Globals()

    globals.setDeviceToken("test1") //method1 not working
    globals.deviceToken = "test2"   //method2 not working
}
```

This is my Globals Class:

```
public class Globals {
    var deviceToken = String()

    init() {
        //nothing
    }

    func setDeviceToken(s:String){
        deviceToken = s
    }

    func getDeviceToken() -> String {
        return deviceToken
    }
}
```

If i try to print the value, from other files of the project, I'm not able to get anything, just an empty string.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Global Variables Class Instance
    let globals:Globals = Globals()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println(globals.getDeviceToken())  //return empty string
        println(globals.deviceToken)       //return empty string
```

Comment: How much data should be held in the app delegate? NONE! EVER! Don't do it. It isn't what the app delegate is for.

Comment: There is no need to get upset, I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to learn. @Fogmeister

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several patterns you can use to achieve what you want

1. You could access the AppDelegate through the UIApplication:

   ```
   let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
   let deviceToken = delegate.deviceToken
   ```
2. Look into singletons. A quick google search for 'Swift singleton' will get you a long way. The first result:

   ```
   class SingletonB {

           class var sharedInstance : SingletonB {
           struct Static {
               static let instance : SingletonB = SingletonB()
           }
           return Static.instance
       }
   }
   ```

Then use `sharedInstance` to instantiate the singleton anywhere and access the same variables.

The first one is quick and dirty, so for more serious projects I would recommend the singleton pattern.

There are probably a million ways to do this, but this should get you started

(More at this link, which explores a few ways to implement singletons: https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I never used singleton and need to read some documentation about it. But the code looks very similar to the one I was using for Globals. @Bob Vork

Comment: As documented in the linked-to article, the above rather convoluted way of creating a singleton is not needed if you're using Swift 1.2 or later.

Answer (score 5):

I simply solved my problem using NSUserDefaults

in the AppDelegate:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

From other classes:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("deviceToken")
```

Honestly I don't know if this is a good way to do it but it's working

Comment: hi! I'd like to know why it is not recommended to use NSUserDefaults ?

Comment: mattyU you need to ask @Fogmeister up here, cause he commented my question

Comment: NSUserdefaults takes time to store data, and you can't store any type of data without trouble. NSUserdefaults should only be used to save data between sessions.